# Phonegap Build -- No splashscreen

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap build app that I want to hide the splashscreen all together in. I don't want the default one to show, and I don't have one to add -- I just want no splashscreen. Ideally, I should be able to do this in the config.xml, but I am open to other solutions -- does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you resolve your problem or not??

Comment: @James I haven't found a solution yet that works with build -- one hack I may try is just a black image in place of a splashscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the default splash screen image in your project directory. Cordova refers to this image and loads it first when the application starts.If no image is present it simply refers to your index file.This worked for me for my Cordova 3.1 project.

The alternative to this is to remove the splashscreen reference manually

Comment: +1. This solution looks great with the cordova cli -- but not with phonegap build. I am looking for an answer that supports phonegap build. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(e) 
{
window.setTimeout(function() {
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
},5000);
}, "false");
```

I hope it will work !!!

Comment: how can I do this with the config.xml?

Comment: @TJonS Please check here http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/4/23/Note-about-PhoneGap-Build-and-Splash-Screens

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you go into the root `config.xml` file you can remove the `cordova-plugin-splashscreen` plugin and then if you clean out the plugins and platforms folders and re-run it will be gone.

```
<!--<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />-->
```